# Git-bash using wrong version of Python

Tags: python, git-bash

I am new to git-bash and am currently trying to make the Git Bash use the correct version of Python. I just installed version 3.8.1, but Git is using the 3.7.3 version.

When I run the `which python` command, it displays the directory of the 3.7.3 Python as expected. How can I switch it so that it is using the updated version?

Let's say, for example, the location of the Python I want to use is `/c/Users/tom/Python3.8.1/python`.

I am tried to solve this by searching online and I came across a post that suggested I use the following command:

```
PATH="path to executable python":PATH
```

But that did not seem to work as after I ran that, it would no longer let me use the `which python` command

Comment: My guess is that the Bash would be inheriting the path settings from your system (Windows or Linux).  Have you tried updating your local path with the latest version of Python (assuming you do want to use that version everywhere) ?

Comment: That command is missing a `$` in front of the second `PATH`. You should edit it in the Windows environment variable dialog instead, though – probably helpful to start by uninstalling Python 3.7.3.

Comment: @Ry-silly me. That solved it.. Thank you for pointing that out.